# How to combine text with spaces in to a single column in R?

Tags: r

My last column ("details") has information that has spaces or tabs. How can I read all details as a single column in R?

input

```
date    month   year    type    expenditure details
10/31/2017  Oct 2017    food    10.89   Point Of Sale Withdrawal 17203473997 TRESIDDER U2           STANFORD     CAUS
10/31/2017  Oct 2017    uber    4.80    Point Of Sale Withdrawal 44519795098 UBER   TRIP F73MU      HELP.UBER.COMCAUS
10/31/2017  Oct 2017    instacart   99.00   Point Of Sale Withdrawal 44534891998 INSTACART SUBSCRIPTION HTTPSINSTACARCAUS
10/31/2017  Oct 2017    food    8.45    Point Of Sale Withdrawal 22607113998 CLARK CENTER-BIO-X CAF STANFORD     CAUS
10/31/2017  Oct 2017    food    4.00    Point Of Sale Withdrawal 33426639883 COUPA CAFE Y2E2        STANFORD     CAUS
10/31/2017  Oct 2017    uber    4.52    Point Of Sale Withdrawal 42029000200217 UBER TRIP QZ7W5 HELP.UB800-5928996  CAUS
10/30/2017  Oct 2017    food    5.85    Point Of Sale Withdrawal 44519950998 UBER   TRIP HOOMP      HELP.UBER.COMCAUS
10/30/2017  Oct 2017    uber    23.20   Point Of Sale Withdrawal 33428390882 COUPA CAFE LYTTON      PALO ALTO    CAUS
10/30/2017  Oct 2017    food    7.52    Point Of Sale Withdrawal 34530890882 PANDA EXPRESS #2035    STANFORD     CAUS
```

Comment: What exact output do you want?  `details` is already a single column.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen - I'm assuming OP is reading from a text file that contains this information as shown. A big assumption I know - maybe OP can clarify?

Comment: yes it is a text file where details is not a single column. When I try to read in R, I get the following error that says file has more columns than column names. @thelatemail

Comment: What are the delimiters in your text file (i.e. what tells us when a given column ends and another one begins) ?

Comment: tabs are the delimiters @TimBiegeleisen

Comment: Oh... it's just tab delimited, then `read.table("filename.txt", sep="\t", header=TRUE)`

Comment: @thelatemail it is tab delimited but the details has so much information with spaces, double spaces and triple spaces. That was the real problem.

Comment: it may be that the `readr` package would provide some assistance over the base file import functions

Comment: @user1883491 - as long as the `details` column doesn't have tabs, it shouldn't matter. If it does have tabs embedded within a column, then you're out of luck really. I can't see how a package is going to fix that issue really.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is an Excel file you can use one of R packages to read the file into excel. I used your example data and open it with `openxlsx`, which doesn't need java, and it read the details column as you want it.
The code would be:

```
read.xlsx("file", detectDates = T)
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not an expert on this, but I found a way that works. It uses `readLines` to read in every line from your file as a single string, and then split the first five words (columns `date`, `month`, `year`, `type` and `expenditure`) and uses the remainder of the line as a final column `details`:

```
raw_txt <- readLines("123.txt")

splitted <- lapply(strsplit(raw_txt[-1], " +"), function(x){
   one_to_five <- x[1:5]
   six         <- paste0(x[5:length(x)], collapse=" ")
   c(one_to_five, six)
})

# Bind together the elements in "splitted":
df <- do.call(rbind, splitted)

# Give the columns the right names:
colnames(df) <- strsplit(raw_txt[1], " +")[[1]]
```

---

**Result:**

```
      date         month year   type        expenditure details                                                                               
 [1,] "10/31/2017" "Oct" "2017" "food"      "10.89"     "10.89 Point Of Sale Withdrawal 17203473997 TRESIDDER U2 STANFORD CAUS"               
 [2,] "10/31/2017" "Oct" "2017" "uber"      "4.80"      "4.80 Point Of Sale Withdrawal 44519795098 UBER TRIP F73MU HELP.UBER.COMCAUS"         
 [3,] "10/31/2017" "Oct" "2017" "instacart" "99.00"     "99.00 Point Of Sale Withdrawal 44534891998 INSTACART SUBSCRIPTION HTTPSINSTACARCAUS" 
 [4,] "10/31/2017" "Oct" "2017" "food"      "8.45"      "8.45 Point Of Sale Withdrawal 22607113998 CLARK CENTER-BIO-X CAF STANFORD CAUS"      
 [5,] "10/31/2017" "Oct" "2017" "food"      "4.00"      "4.00 Point Of Sale Withdrawal 33426639883 COUPA CAFE Y2E2 STANFORD CAUS"             
 [6,] "10/31/2017" "Oct" "2017" "uber"      "4.52"      "4.52 Point Of Sale Withdrawal 42029000200217 UBER TRIP QZ7W5 HELP.UB800-5928996 CAUS"
 [7,] "10/30/2017" "Oct" "2017" "food"      "5.85"      "5.85 Point Of Sale Withdrawal 44519950998 UBER TRIP HOOMP HELP.UBER.COMCAUS"         
 [8,] "10/30/2017" "Oct" "2017" "uber"      "23.20"     "23.20 Point Of Sale Withdrawal 33428390882 COUPA CAFE LYTTON PALO ALTO CAUS"         
 [9,] "10/30/2017" "Oct" "2017" "food"      "7.52"      "7.52 Point Of Sale Withdrawal 34530890882 PANDA EXPRESS #2035 STANFORD CAUS"
```